# How do I output in Views just the variables' values I want in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, methods, for-loop

Now in my application.html.erb in views folder, I wrote this.

```
<p>List of all post IDs: <%= Post.all.each {|i| print i.id } %></p>
```

I would like it to output just the post.id of each post. But instead it shows this

```
List of all post IDs: [#<Post id: 1, title: "Our First Post", content: "Content for our first post", created_at: "2012-11-24 11:22:02", updated_at: "2012-11-26 17:40:54", user_id: 1>, #<Post id: 3, title: "Our Second Post", content: "Content for our second post", created_at: "2012-11-24 11:51:32", updated_at: "2012-11-26 17:41:33", user_id: 2>, #<Post id: 8, title: "Our Second Post", content: "Content of Our mandatory Second Post", created_at: "2012-11-24 19:42:02", updated_at: "2012-11-27 20:46:57", user_id: 1>, #<Post id: 10, title: "C Post", content: "Hi I'm Cee nice to meet you", created_at: "2012-11-26 17:51:20", updated_at: "2012-11-26 17:51:20", user_id: 3>, #<Post id: 20, title: "11", content: "11", created_at: "2012-11-27 19:58:48", updated_at: "2012-11-27 19:58:48", user_id: 4>, #<Post id: 21, title: "22", content: "22", created_at: "2012-11-27 19:58:53", updated_at: "2012-11-27 19:58:53", user_id: 4>, #<Post id: 25, title: "I'm Super Singha!", content: "Yessar!!!", created_at: "2012-11-27 20:45:07", updated_at: "2012-11-27 20:45:07", user_id: 6>, #<Post id: 26, title: "Should this be a blog or a forums or a whatever-wha...", content: ";asljdfi;asfi;asdf;lasbfurbofioboboeifhosdsdbvisbvw...", created_at: "2012-11-27 20:46:28", updated_at: "2012-12-02 14:17:14", user_id: 1>, #<Post id: 27, title: "Hullow", content: "Yoyoyo", created_at: "2012-11-30 07:35:38", updated_at: "2012-11-30 07:35:54", user_id: 6>, #<Post id: 649, title: "um", content: "hey", created_at: "2012-11-30 12:20:58", updated_at: "2012-11-30 12:20:58", user_id: 2>, #<Post id: 82692, title: "LALALALAL", content: "hiopsdahfiosadhfioahfio", created_at: "2012-12-02 13:59:04", updated_at: "2012-12-02 14:22:41", user_id: 2>, #<Post id: 82693, title: "ggg", content: "fff", created_at: "2012-12-02 14:29:42", updated_at: "2012-12-02 14:29:42", user_id: 2>, #<Post id: 82694, title: "sick", content: "sick", created_at: "2012-12-02 14:41:32", updated_at: "2012-12-02 14:41:32", user_id: 5>]
```

I have tried, `puts` instead of `print`, that doesn't work either.

Further: I would also like to make a link_to each post show page from the intended result, how can I achieve that?

Here's my repo: https://github.com/nixor/cpblog , here's heroku site: http://still-plains-5469.herokuapp.com/

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever read a tutorial on Rails Views? checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#using-the-console

Comment: No, I have only learned Rails for one week. But hey now I will never reach 15 reputition to upvote anyone to show my appreciation now if I get downvoted like this. But thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how you are using the ERB tags here:

```
<%= Post.all.each {|i| print i.id } %>
```

Whenever you use `<%=`, the result of the block will be rendered. In your case, `Post.all.each {}` returns an array object, which is exactly what you are seeing in your rendered HTML.

In order to print out each item, you will need to loop through the items using `<%` and then print out what you want using `<%=`.

```
<p>List of all post IDs: 
  <% Post.all.each |post| do %>
    <%= link_to post.id, post_path(post) %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>List of all post IDs: 
</p>
<%= Post.all.each do |e| %>
  <p>
    <%= e.Id %>
  <p>
  <%= link_to "Show", e %> 
<% end %>
```